# The necessary force to lift a block-spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, free-body-diagram, spring

Consider a situation with two blocks with a spring between them vertically. I am interested in the compression required in order to lift the system of the ground? What is the force required to do this?

[image]

I've drawn what I think the forces will act like, but don't know how to find out how much force is required in order to make the lower block leave the floor.

Just compressing it shouldn't be able to cause any change, in the same way that pushing a block of mass (M+m) down with greater force doesn't cause it to bounce up.

I do know that the normal force equals zero when the condition for lift off from the ground is fulfilled.

*How do we go about doing such a question?*
*The intuition behind why a compression would cause the lower block to be lifted up.*

Comment: You have made correct fbd.  Just when contact in about to break N becomes 0 so kx=mg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation is different from a single block in the way that the spring between the blocks  is capable of storing and releasing  energy.

> The intuition behind why a compression would cause the lower block to be lifted up.

The intuition here is the fact that  a massless spring applies  $\texttt
 {equal force on both it's ends.}$

When  the block is pushed down further and released it will try to oscillate and in the process the spring will be elongated from its natural length. Thus, it will apply a force on lower block too.

The thing that  needs to be done is to calculate the force to be applied initially so that the block reaches a height to produce an eligation  $x$  such that $Kx=Mg$.

Comment: So if both the masses were equal(m&m), i would just need to apply a force mg downwards on the upper block and leave the system,and the lower block would just leave the ground?